# Misaligned options in date select dropdown (Firefox)

Tags: html, css, firefox

in Firefox this date select dropdown has misalgined options. See the following image:

[image: Misgaligned date]

Any tips on what I can do to make the options line up?

CSS for this here:

```
.dob-selects-container {
  display: block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  min-height: 30px;
  margin-left: 2.12766%;

  :nth-child(1) {
    width: 120px;
    display: inline-block
  }

  :nth-child(2) {
    width: 60px;
    display: inline-block
  }

  :nth-child(3) {
    width: 80px;
    display: inline-block
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply specify style rules using `:nth-child()` it'll apply to all matching elements.

You've specified `display:inline-block` for the first 3 childs using child selectors, hence they will sit next to each other like text. `March` is pulled down since it doesn't have any space available in the same line..

If you were trying to apply it just for the `<select>` elements, try

```
select:nth-child(1) {
 width: 120px;
 display: inline-block
}
```